# Findbugs warning: Integer shift by 32 -- what does it mean?

Tags: java, findbugs, bit

I was scanning a third party source code using Findbugs (just to be cautious before integrating into it mine), and found the following warning:

```
long a = b << 32 | c
```

> Bug: Integer shift by 32 Pattern id:
>   ICAST_BAD_SHIFT_AMOUNT, type: BSHIFT,
>   category: CORRECTNESS
>
> The code performs an integer shift by
>   a constant amount outside the range
>   0..31. The effect of this is to use the lower 5 bits of the integer value
>   to decide how much to shift by. This
>   probably isn't want was expected, and
>   it at least confusing.

Could anyone please explain what exactly does the above mean?

Thanks!
(I am quite a newbie in Java programming)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.19):

> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is int, only the five lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a bitwise logical AND operator & (§15.22.1) with the mask value 0x1f. The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the range 0 to 31, inclusive.

So if b is an int, the expression is identical to

```
long a = b | c;
```

which I highly doubt is what is intended. It should probably have been

```
long a = ((long) b << 32) | c;
```

(If b is already a long, the code is correct and FindBugs is mistaken about the bug).

Comment: So, `int >> 32(0x100000) == int >> 0(0x00000)`?

Comment: Strange pseudo-syntax you use, but yes, that's it.

Answer (score 5):

*Edited:* The problem almost certainly stems from the fact that 'b' is an 'int' and not a 'long'.

In C, if 'b' is an integer instead of a long and you shift left by 32 bits, <s>all the bits from the original value have been removed, so the result of the overall expression would be the same as 'c'</s> you would invoke undefined behaviour, so any result is permissible.  Java defines things differently — as noted in the comment by Rasmus Faber and the chosen answer — and does overlong shifts modulo the maximum number of bits that can be shifted.  [It seems an odd way to do business; I'd probably have arranged for an exception in a language that has them.  However, it is clearly defined, which is more important than exactly what the definition is.] The coercion to 64-bits doesn't occur while the expression is evaluated; it occurs when the expression is complete and the assignment happens.

The reference to 5 bits is ... intriguing.  It means that if you shift left by, say, 48, or binary 110000, it is the same as shifting left by 16.  Or, alternatively, '`x << n`' is the same as '`x << (n % 32)`'.

Comment: The first part of your answer is incorrect. In Jave, b << 32 is b, not zero. The second paragraåh is correct, however.

Comment: Correction: In C behavior is _undefined_ when shifting a value with argument outside range [0, typewidth - 1]. For example the opencl compilers from nvidia and intel gives me different behavior for the expression 'b >> 32'.

Comment: same problem with `<long> << 64` :(