# (-1 >>> 32) == -1?

Tags: java, expression, operator-keyword, bit-shift, shift

Why the expression `(-1 >>> 32)` in Java is evaluated to `-1` instead of `0` as expected? The `>>>`-shift-operator should fill in preceeding 0s, so the result should have all bits set to 0.

This is weird, because it breaks the semantics of `>>>`: e.g. `(-1 >>> x)` has the first x bits set to 0 for all `0 <= x <= 31`. The only (unexpected) exception is 32.

Is this intentional behaviour, a bug or an (overmotivated) compiler optimization?

I used the expression `~(-1 >>> x)` for expanding a cidr-netmask to its 32-bit equivalent, but as it seems, /32-masks have to be handled separately.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023373/findbugs-warning-integer-shift-by-32-what-does-it-mean).

Quote from answer author [Rasmus Faber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5542/rasmus-faber)

> From the Java Language Specification:
>
> > If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is int, only the five
> >     lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift
> >     distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a
> >     bitwise logical AND operator & (§15.22.1) with the mask value 0x1f.
> >     The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the range 0 to
> >     31, inclusive.

Long in short: due to operand range limit, `-1 >>> 32` is equivalent to `-1 >>> 0` which is `-1`.