# Java right shift integer by 32

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I am trying to right shift an integer by 32 but the result is the same number.
(e.g. `5 >> 32` is 5.)

If I try to do same operation on Byte and Short it works. For example, "(byte)5 >> 8" is 0.

What is wrong with Integer?

Comment: Byte is 8 bit and short is 16 bit but why they work?

Comment: can this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023373/findbugs-warning-integer-shift-by-32-what-does-it-mean

Comment: @TheLostMind Although that is true from the perspective of the JLS, shifting is not the same as a rotate which your comment seems to imply.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel totally agree. That java wraps its shift amount is an annoying bug in the language. I.e. shifting 8 bit behaves as shifting 32 bit, but shifting 64 bit suddenly differs... wtf were they smoking?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[JLS 15.19. Shift Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19)

> ... If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is int, **only the five lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand** are used as the shift distance.

so shifting `32` is not effective.

Comment: This is the real answer.  The OP's code behaves that way (fundamentally) because the Java Language Specification says it **must**.

Answer (score 1):

A Shifting conversion returns result as an `int` or `long`. So, even if you shift a `byte`, you will get an `int` back.

Java code :

```
public static void main(String s[]) {
    byte b = 5;
    System.out.println(b >> 8);
    int i = 8;
    System.out.println(i >> 32);
}
```

Byte code :

```
         0: iconst_5
         1: istore_1
         2: getstatic     #16                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream; 
         5: iload_1
         6: bipush        8
         8: ishr
         9: invokevirtual #22      // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V  ==> Using println(int)
        12: bipush        8
        14: istore_2
        15: getstatic     #16     // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
        18: iload_2
        19: bipush        32
        21: ishr
        22: invokevirtual #22      // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V   ==> Using println(int)
        25: return
```

Comment: @Codebender - I didn't say that it was *circular*

Comment: 1) Disassembling bytecodes is only helpful for people who can read them fluently.  That is probably less than 5% of Java programmers. 2) It only shows what a particular compiler generates.  Who is to say if the compiler has got it right?  Or if there may be other bytecode sequences that behave differently and are also "right"?

Comment: @StephenC - I chose to un-delete this answer despite of numerous downvotes because byte-code provides valuable info here. All shifts result in either int or long. Shifting `byte` still results in an `int`.

Comment: @Codebender - It was like explaining it in *layman's terms*. Shift is not circular.

Comment: That is your opinion.  My opinion is that the bytecodes don't prove anything.  And they provide the information in an obfuscated fashion.  See my comments above.  This applies to just about any answer to a Java question that includes disassembled bytecodes.  It is a really poor way of conveying information to human beings, and especially to novice Java programmers.

Comment: @StephenC -I agree. I find it easier to check byte code and come to conclusions (which is perhaps wrong sometimes :P) instead of looking for proper jls sections

Comment: Yes ... the JLS spec is the right place to go for a definitive answer.  And if you are saying that bytecode dumps are a lazy way to answer ... I agree with that too :-)

Comment: thx. this is the first time i've read disassembled bytecode. it was totally helpful. so it seems that method local variables "byte b=5" and "int b=5" would even generate nearly the same bytecode (in this example), no conversion is happening at runtime.
"iconst_5" and "bipush 8" are the only difference. i assume that would be optimized in the next compiler step.